# Cant run csv file in R language

Tags: r, csv

I am new at R language and I want to run a csv file.

I have this code:

```
origData <- read.csv2('./data/raw_201501.csv', sep=",", header=TRUE)
```

The problem is that it doesnt find the dataset:raw_201501.csv.
Where should I store this dataset raw_201501.csv in order to execute the code? Maybe in a certain dorectory?

Thanks

Comment: Check whether your working directory in R (with `getwd()`) is the same as the location of the file.

Comment: BTW: `read.csv2(filename, sep=",")` is identical to `read.csv(filename)` (without `sep`).

Comment: I suggest you read the help for [`?getwd`, `?setwd`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/getwd.html), as well as [`?list.files`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.files.html). RStudio does allow menu-driver control of directories as well as [Projects](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects), but there is no replacing understanding it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using R Studio, the best way if you're new is go to the session menu up top, and change the working directory to the directory that has the file. Then when you call it in read.csv2 you can get rid of './'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file.choose()` function to open a new window. This will help you to find the file path.

```
## read csv
df <- read.csv2(file = file.choose(), sep=",", header=TRUE)
```